# Nested attributes values are not returned on EDIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, edit, nested-attributes

When I `edit` a object, the relationship object values are not displayed in the `edit` form. The create on other hand is working.

Here are the models:

```
class LogFile < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :config_file, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :config_file, allow_destroy: true
end

class ConfigFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :log_file
end
```

and this is the controller:

```
 # GET /log_files/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_log_file
      @log_file = LogFile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def log_file_params
      params.require(:log_file).permit(
                                       :name,
                                       :user_id,
                                       config_file_attributes: [:id, :json, :_destroy]
                                       )
    end
```

The form looks like this:

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file_attributes do |n| %>
    <%= n.input :json %>
 <% end %>
```

I have firstly try to `join` or `include` the relationship model, but was not able to do it. Some of the folks said thar `id` in the `permit()` function do the trick, but nothing changes in my situation.

Could anyone advice what to try?

---

Also when I put the following code in the form template:

```
<%= debug @log_file %>
```

no details about the relationship model are returned.

---

This is the solution I have apply using the accepted answer:

```
  <% if @log_file.id %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file do |n| %>
          <%= n.input :json %>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file_attributes do |n| %>
          <%= n.input :json %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: It's normal that @log_file doesn't show related object, you should be able to access it inside the nested from area, but what are you trying to (access) show upon editing?

Comment: The `config_file` has a `json` field. I am able to populate it on create, but when I edit a record, the field is displayed as empty. I want to display its value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using relation name without `_attributes` suffix:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file do |n| %>
  <%= n.input :json %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It works, but it breaks the `create` method now. Is there any standard fix for this, or I should check if I am updating and render it without attribute part?

Comment: on `create` the nested form was not rendered.

Comment: ah, you need to build an object in the new action, something like `@log_file.config_file.build` so when the form is rendered there is a config_file for your log_file just waiting to be saved